# Python: Check times function is returning in while

Tags: python, time

First time poster here, wondering what the best way is to check the times a function is returning a value in a certain period of time. For example: x is returning 7 times a value in 10 seconds. I have a measure_time function which returns the time it takes to tap a certain pattern of keys. In the while loop i'm checking the elapsed time and inside the while i want to check if the measure_time function returns something. Any suggestions on where i go wrong?

```
start = time.time()
time.clock()
elapsed = 0
runs = 0
while elapsed < seconds:
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    if self.measure_time():
        runs += 1
```

Comment: why `time.clock()`? Where the `self` in `self.measure_time()` comes from?

Comment: Timeit might come in handy https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: *Why* do you think you "go wrong"? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?